# onclick not firing on first click (answer only in Plain Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my Html Code

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-correct" name="checkCheckbox"
         onclick="addRightAnswer();">
  <input type="text"
         placeholder="Enter your option"
         class="form-control-range-number"
         id="get-radio-input5"
         name="get-radio-input"><input
  type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0"
  name="get-radio-input"/>
  <button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i
    class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i
    class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-correct" name="checkCheckbox"
         onclick="addRightAnswer();">
  <input type="text"
         placeholder="Enter your option"
         class="form-control-range-number"
         id="get-radio-input5"
         name="get-radio-input">
  <input
    type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0"
    name="get-radio-input"/>
  <button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i
    class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i
    class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-correct" name="checkCheckbox"
         onclick="addRightAnswer();">
  <input type="text"
         placeholder="Enter your option"
         class="form-control-range-number"
         id="get-radio-input5"
         name="get-radio-input">
  <input
    type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0"
    name="get-radio-input"/>
  <button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i
    class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i
    class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-correct" name="checkCheckbox"
         onclick="addRightAnswer();">
  <input type="text"
         placeholder="Enter your option"
         class="form-control-range-number"
         id="get-radio-input5"
         name="get-radio-input">
  <input
    type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0"
    name="get-radio-input"/>
  <button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i
    class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i
    class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

This is my Javascript Code

```
function addRightAnswer() {
var getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.input-checkbox-correct');
var getRadioInputNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.get-radio-input-number');

  getRadioOptionsNumberCheck.forEach(function(current, index) {
    current.addEventListener('click', function() {

      if (current.checked) {
        getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 1; //
      } 
      else
      {
        getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 0;
      }  

    });
  });
}
```

initially value is 0 after one click value wiill increase by 1 , but in my case everything is working But First click on Checkbox value is not increasing in 2nd click value is increasing

Comment: Why do you test `current.checked` twice?

Comment: if i remove this then also it is not working

Comment: I know, it has nothing to do with the problem. `x || x` is the same as just `x` for any `x`.

Comment: i have removed. but still i ma facing same issue

Comment: I already said it has nothing to do with the problem, why do you think it would make a difference?

Comment: BTW, you have several elements with the same id of "get-radio-input5". That's invalid, all ids must be unique. Also, "click" is not a valid button type, must be type="button|submit|reset".

Comment: Never heard of `button type="click"`

Comment: it is only name. there is nothing use of this type="click"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add an Event Listener if you already call `addRightAnswer()` on click.

Right now when you click the checkbox, you add the event listener, which will then modify the input value at the next click.

```js
function addRightAnswer() {
  var getRadioOptionsNumberCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.input-checkbox-correct');
  var getRadioInputNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.get-radio-input-number');

  getRadioOptionsNumberCheck.forEach(function(current, index) {

      if (current.checked) {
        getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 1; //
      } else {
        getRadioInputNumber[index].value = 0;
      }

  });
}
```

```html
<div><input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-correct" name="checkCheckbox" onclick="addRightAnswer();"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your option" class="form-control-range-number" id="get-radio-input5" name="get-radio-input"><input type="number"
    class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input" /><button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="click" onclick="removeOptions(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
```